# How do I calculate opportunity stage convestion rate %

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, business-logic

I want to conversion rate.
Let say 100 opportunities in 1 stage then they 50 opportunities moved to 2 stage so stage conversion rate is 50%. then 25 moved to 2 stage from those 50 opportunities so again stage conversion rate is 50% but over all is 25% because out of 100 only 25 moved to stage 3.
So I want both conversion rate in my report.
1. Stage by stage conversion rate
2. overall conversion rate.

how can I get it. what approach should I follow.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I built a matrix report using Opportunity History. On the left, I added From Stage. At the top, I added To Stage.  This gave me the number of opportunities that moved from each stage, and which stage they moved to (to account for skipped stages). From there, I built a bar graph that shows the From Stage with record count on the left. That way, I can see how many move from each stage.

Unless you delete Opportunities out of Stage 1, Stage 1 should always show the total number of Opportunities. If you do delete Opportunities out of Stage 1, then this may not be your solution. For us, if an Opportunity is not viable at Stage 1, or we simply prefer not to spend the resources on that piece of business, we will close the Opportunity as Lost and select a custom reason code indicating that we chose not to participate in that Opportunity.